# bazel can't build py_proto_library

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, bazel

My BUILD file is pretty simple, just

```
load("@protobuf_bzl//:protobuf.bzl", "py_proto_library")

py_proto_library(
name = "struct_py_pb2",
srcs = ["struct.proto"],
)
```

But bazel gives a bunch of baffling error messages like:

```
$ bazel build google/genomics/v1:all
ERROR: thomaswc//v1/BUILD:22:1: no such package '': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//v1:struct_py_pb2'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//v1:struct_py_pb2' failed; build aborted: no such package '': BUILD file not found on package path
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.581s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (2 packages loaded)
currently loading: @protobuf_bzl//
```

I see other projects on github using bazel and py_proto_library, though, so I know it must be possible.  Is there some WORKSPACE or .bzl magic that I need?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619281/why-is-a-publicly-visible-bazel-protobuf-target-not-declared/46654679#46654679

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of digging, I found a work-around:  the default values of `default_runtime` and `protoc` are screwed up, so you need to override them:

```
py_proto_library(
    name = "struct_py_pb2",
    srcs = ["struct.proto"],
    default_runtime = "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_python",
    protoc = "@com_google_protobuf//:protoc",
)
```